# Django Rest Framework, custom page_size for list_route action

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a list_route:

```
    @list_route(methods=['get'])
    def bought(self, request):
        bought_photos = Photo.objects.filter(is_bought=True)

        page = self.paginate_queryset(bought_photos)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(bought_photos, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

How can I set a custom page_size only for the list_route, not for its ModelViewSet?

**SOLUTION**

1) create CustomPagination class

```
from rest_framework.pagination import PageNumberPagination

class CustomPagination(PageNumberPagination):
    page_size = 10000
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
```

2) edit the list_route code:

```
   @list_route(methods=['get'])
   def bought(self, request):
        bought_photos = Photo.objects.filter(is_bought=True)
        paginator = CustomPagination()

        page = paginator.paginate_queryset(bought_photos, request)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return paginator.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(bought_photos, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code should be enough:

```
@list_route(methods=['get'], pagination_class=CustomPagination)
def bought(self, request):
    bought_photos = Photo.objects.filter(is_bought=True)

    page = self.paginate_queryset(bought_photos)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(bought_photos, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: It's a really brief mention in the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) "The decorators can additionally take extra arguments that will be set for the routed view only. For example..."

Comment: I'm amazed to read great answers about some very advanced topics and somehow hidden features of a framework. It's a shame that this answer hasn't been honored. Just one remark: `page` should be of type `list`, so it can't be `None`, so it will always enter the if-clause. If the list is empty then it shouldn't enter the if-clause, thus the condition should better be `if page:`. Or maybe I have got something wrong?